# Page layouts and render format

Tags: 2013, cross-site-publishing

We are trying to customize how a catalog-item reuse page work in a cross-site publishing scenario. We have our catalog hooked up and are using the page to successfully show data in our publishing site. Now we want to format and control how that data looks.

Found this documentation on [Understanding the markup in the HTML catalog item page layout] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn144674.aspx) near the bottom of the page.

I think a lot of what we need to do is based around the RenderFormat like this:

```
<!--SPM:<RenderFormat>-->
<!--SPM:<Format Type="HTML"> -->
<!--SPM:<Picture>-->True<!--SPM:</Picture>-->
<!--SPM:</Format> -->
<!--SPM:</RenderFormat>-->
```

Where can I find a list of the possible type attributes for the default renderformat tag and the different tags and values that can be nested into it?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [blog post](http://www.eliostruyf.com/client-side-managed-property-value-formatting-catalog-item-page-layouts/) on how to do custom renderings. So if I can't find a list of the official renderers at least I can now make my own!